# Copy fields and value of an object to a Map

Tags: java

I want to copy fields from a complex object- that is an object which contains other objects.
Now it copies wrapper classes with no issue but how do i copy the fields and values of the subclass

code

```
 public Map<String, Object> getValueMapFromInsuranceVehicle(Long insuranceId) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        InsurancePolicy insurance = repository.findById(insuranceId).get();

        Method[] methods = insurance.getInsuranceVehicle().getClass().getMethods();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                Object value =  m.invoke(insurance.getInsuranceVehicle());
                map.put(m.getName().substring(3), value);
            }
        }
        // add other fields specific to our needs like currentYear
        return map;
    }
```

From the code above it copies insuranceVehicle fields correctly, But i would like to copy the whole InsurancePolicy object and put the values in a map.
when i try it with InsurancePolicy i get exception cannot convert InsurancaCalculation into String,

my Insurance policy object looks like this

```
class InsurancePolicy {
    @OneToOne
    private Person person;
    @OneToOne
    private Vehicle vehicle;
    @OneToOne
    private InsurancePolicyStatus status;

    private LocalDate policyStart = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);

    private LocalDate policyEnd = policyStart.plusYears(1).minusDays(1);

    private boolean policy_AC = true;

    private boolean policy_OC = true;

    private boolean policy_ASS;

    private boolean policy_NNW;

    private String vehicleUsageType;
     InsuranceCalculation calculation

    @Embedded
    private InsuranceVehicle insuranceVehicle;

    @Embedded
    private InsuranceCustomer customer;

    private String coownerHowMany;

    private String abroad;

}
```

Finally my question how can i improve my method getValueMapFromInsuranceVehicle() to get more fields copied ?
basically how to make this code below to work

```
 public Map<String, Object> getValueMapFromInsuranceVehicle(Long insuranceId) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        InsurancePolicy insurance = repository.findById(insuranceId).get();

        Method[] methods = insurance.getClass().getMethods();  // insurance instead of vehicle
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                Object value =  m.invoke(insurance); // insurance instead of insurancevehicle
                map.put(m.getName().substring(3), value);
            }
        }
        // add other fields specific to our needs like currentYear
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: This is a very very dirty way to use getters. But maybe you already know that and have your reasons. I want to point to some dangerous point.
`m.getName().substring(3)` Easily you can have 2 getters to have the first 3 letters of their name to be the same. In that case you will invoke only one of those getters.

Comment: Why do you need a Map<String, Object>. Is this a reason for that? Why don't you clone just the InsuranceVehicle object or any other object that you want?

Answer (score 0):

To get the methods of other objects in InsurancePolicy you could use your same code but add some checks for if the object is InsuranceCustomer, InsuranceVehicle, or InsuranceCalculation by using instanceOf and if it is use the same code just with Method[] methods = insurance.getClass().getMethods(); changed to the objects class. I would recommend separating your code into more methods so you can use recursion.